# C++ Final exam study material

Tags: c++

I have been working on this problem in preparation for my coming C++ final exam:

```
// What gets printed?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
  public:
    A(int a = 5) : i(a) { cout << "A" << endl; }
    void foo() { cout << "this.i " << i << endl; }
    virtual void print() const { cout << i << " in A" << endl; }
  protected:
    int i;
};
class B : public A {
  public:
    B() : A(1) { cout << "B default" << endl; }
    void foo() { cout << i << " in B" << endl; }
    void print() const { cout << i << " in B" << endl; }
};
int main() {
  A *pa;
  B b;
  pa=&b;
  pa->foo();
  pa->print();
  return 0;
}
```

And its output is:

```
A
B default
this.i 1
1 in B
```

I understand that the `A` being printed is from calling `B`'s constructor from the superclass `A`, and I understand that making the pointer `*pa` point at `&b` makes it access the base class method for `foo`, but how is it printing the value in `B::print()` instead of `A::print()`?

Comment: Because that's the whole point (no pun intended) of polymorphism...

Comment: I hope you're not graded on format!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, you overrided print() in B. And since foo() is not defined as virtual in class A therefore the foo() from class A is called.

Answer (score 1):

Since `B` is derived from `A`, every `B` *is* an `A`.  So `pa` can point to an object of type `A` or any derived type.  But the type of object doesn't change, so `b` is still of type `B` and behaves as such.  The only restriction is that, since it's being referenced by a pointer to `A`, you can only reference the methods and member variables that are declared in the base class `A`.

For an explanation of *why* C++ works this way, look for a discussion on `vtable`s.

Comment: vtables aren't *why* C++ works, they're *how* it's implemented.  The OP shouldn't need to know anything about vtables in order to understand the semantics of their code.

Comment: Well, yes, and the implementation explains why the code does what it does.  I meant "why" in the "what makes it happen" sense, but not the "what is the intention" sense.  English is complicated.  :-)  I find it easier to understand new things if I can see them at the nuts-and-bolts level.  But I agree that the OP shouldn't _need_ to know about vtables in order to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

```
virtual void print()
```

The word *virtual* in front of function makes the polymorphism do its magic. When a derived class implements a function that is declared virtual in the base class it will be called instead of the base class function for instances of the derived class.

You create an instance of the derived class B and B has a member function called print() there it will be called instead.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between

```
pa->foo();
```

and

```
pa->print();
```

is caused by a simple fact:

> The type of a pointer instructs the compiler as to how to interpret the memory found at a particular address and also just how much memory that interpretation should span

, from book *Inside the C++ object model*.

In other words, when compiler tries to translate this line of code `pa->foo()`, he only knows that *pa* is a pointer of class A and *foo* is function of class A. Although we know in fact *pa* points to a block of memory of class B, compiler doesn't and can't know that fact. He just resolve *pa* as a pointer of class A and find A's definition of function *foo*. Yet the magic of `pa->print()` is due to the *virtual function implementation* of C++. For a normal function, compiler just parse its name and jump to the start address of that function. However, for a virtual function, compiler will first find the *vptr* pointer from the memory pointed by the pointer *pa* and resolve the *vptr* to find the right definition of *print* function. Because this time compiler reads the *vptr* from memory and the memory is in fact belong to class B, B's print will be called.
Here is another example to illustrate it:

```
// What gets printed?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
  public:
int b;
    A(int a = 5) : i(a) { 
      b = 42;
  cout << "A" << endl; 
    }
    void foo() { cout << "this.i " << i << endl; }
    virtual void print() const { cout << i << " in A" << endl; }
   protected:
     int i;
 };
 class B : public A {
   public:
 int b;
     B() : A(1) { 
       b = 43;
   cout << "B default" << endl; }
     void foo() { cout << i << " in B" << endl; }
     void print() const { cout << i << " in B" << endl; }
 };
 int main() {
   A *pa;
   B b;
   pa=&b;
   cout << pa->b << endl;
   cout << b.A::b << ", " << b.b << endl;
   //pa->foo();
   //pa->print();
   return 0;
 }
```

The output is

```
A
B default
42
42, 43
```

By the way, *virtual function mechanism* only works on pointer or reference, because for a object A, `A.print()` must resolve to *vptr* in a block of memory of class A which is A's *print* function